# Promisify a constant value with Bluebird

Tags: promise, bluebird

Using `when.js`, if I need to wrap a constant value in a promise, I write:

```
 p = when(3);

 p.then(...)
```

What's the Bluebird equivalent? Constructing a Promise manually seems to require actually passing `resolve` and `defer` functions.

Comment: [`Promise.resolve`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.resolve.html)

Comment: I guess that other thread has the right answer, but geez that's a horrible title.